# does $\sum n!$ converge to a rational number in $p$-adic sense ? (open problem ?)

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

We know $\sum n!$ converges to some real number when we give the usual $p$-adic norm on $\mathbb{Q}$. But today my teacher told me whether it does converge to some rational is currently an open problem. And I'm getting interested in this problem, can anyone suggest some papers related to progression of solving this one ? Playing up a bit for a while with this problem I've only managed to show it does converge to some non zero real number under $p$ adic norm.

Comment: In what sense are you associating $p$-adic numbers with real numbers?

Comment: Ok, I'm editing, in $p$ adic sense I mean that thing converge to some real number under the usual metric given by $|x|_{p}=p^{-ord_p(x)}$

Comment: [This](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/padic.pdf) is a paper about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{k}n!$ which is related to your question..

Comment: @NTlearner95: How are you measuring real numbers in a $p$-adic sense? Did you mean to talk about $\sum n!$ converging to a **$p$-adic number**?

Comment: In my edited version there is no mention of "$p$-adic sense". To be precise what I want is converging of $\sum n!$ converges to some real number under $p$-adic metric, by what I mean is getting a real $x$ such that $|(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i!) -x|_{p} < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$

Comment: NT what is your actual background?

Comment: did I say anything non sense ? :O

Comment: But anyways the paper given by See-Woo Lee is exactly what I wanted

Comment: @NTlearner95: Yes, you have said nonsense: you keep insisting on plugging *real* numbers into the $p$-adic norm.

Comment: But that's what was said by our teacher in class. So what should call them ? like p aidic real ? btw I have done just one class in p adic number, so I don;t have any experience at all other than knowing what is p adic norm :(

Comment: If your teacher said “convergent to a real number”, (s)he was in serious error. That series converges to a genuine $p$-adic number, and if that should turn out to be a rational number, you’d expect a different rational for each $p$.

Comment: There's no canonical and natural association between real numbers and $p$-adic numbers.  However if the number is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$ then any embedding of your $p$-adic field into $\Bbb C$ will take that number to one of finitely many places (the other roots of its minimal polynomial).  So to some extent it makes sense to talk about $\sqrt 2$ as both a $p$-adic and real number.  But for at transcendental numbers like $\pi$ there's no natural association you can essentially associate it with any transcendetal number over $\bar{\Bbb Q}_p$.

Comment: @gregory there are transcendental numbers definable in $p$-adic integers.  For example, $\log(4n+1)$, n any integer, is a $2$-adic integer.  But we cannot in general extract real and imaginary parts of complex numbers, so we can't extract $\pi$, for example, from the $2$-adic logarithm of $-3$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, in fact the complete and algebraically complete $p$-adic fields are all isomorphic to $\Bbb C$ it's just that it's somewhat arbitrary how to map the transcendental elements in such an isomorphism, you have to evoke the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 4):

This must be said: every prime bigger than $2$ has a $p$-adically convergent sequence with limit $\sqrt{-p + 1\,}$, unquestionably nonreal. For $p=2$, the same can be said about $\sqrt{-7\,}$.

Comment: How one can show the existence of such square roots? Probably using the Hensel lemma, right?

Comment: You can use Hensel,or, more primitively, just use Binomial Series to expand $(1-p)^{1/2}$. It works because there are no $p$’s in the denominators of the coefficients of the series. For $\sqrt{-7}$ you need to know that the formal series $(1+4x)^{1/2}$ has all its coefficients in $\Bbb Z$.